# Which double arrow after line break

Tags: notation

I wrote something like this in a paper.
$$a=b*c$$
$$\Leftrightarrow c=a / b$$

My professor corrected the double arrow with $\Updownarrow$. This is it the first time I encountered this symbol. Usually I use the one from left to right. Which arrow should I use after a line break?

Comment: I guess the arrow technically should point to each of the two things it should point to. That being said, I don't think what you wrote is that bad, and it's common enough.

Comment: I've never seen the up and down one either. A journal editor might well reject it. You might consider aligning the $=$ signs, or using words "if and only if".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean the same thing, but I might use them slightly differently.  For example
\begin{align}
A &\iff B \\
& \iff C
\end{align}
(note that the arrows align vertically), versus
\begin{gather}
A \\
\Updownarrow \\
B \\
\Updownarrow \\
C.
\end{gather}
I like the former better, but if the lines were very very long, or if one needed a little extra visual space, or if there were a commutative diagram running around, the latter might be preferable.

In case of the original statement, I probably wouldn't have even bothered with a line break, and would have simply written
$$ a = b\ast c \iff c = a/b.$$